# Firefox Code Inspector: how to find a function in linked .js files

Tags: javascript, json, debugging

I'm trying to debug a page that is linked to a .JSON the relevant field code is as follow:

```
<input type="text" name="company" 
 typeahead="company.description for company in retrieveCompanies($viewValue)" ...>
```

The function above is called while typing into the control to show elements containing the letter that we typed; using Firefox Code Inspector, ho do i find the source of `retrieveCompanies($viewValue)` function? If firefox is executing this command it must know where is it located, since it is not in the same page it must come from a linked .js file.

**EDIT**: after the last comment I was able to find the function is javascript, here is the source code, yet I have to figure out where it is populated, it seems that this code generate chema html pages (data consumer?) but doesnt show where the data come from:

```js
define("text!accounts/widgets/domiciliazione-utenze/states/create/prepare/_views/addressbook-new.html", [], function() {
        return '<div class="cb-recipient-panel cb-recipient-new padding-top" cb-parentpointer="{{\'new-contact\'}}" cb-children=""\n     cb-pointer-show="true">\n    <div class="col-xs-12">\n        <h4>\n            <strong>{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.addDebit\' | translate}}</strong>\n        </h4>\n    </div>\n    <form id="addressbookForm_form" name="addressbookForm_form"\n          cb-validation-schema="domiciliazione-utenze/schema/addressbook-new"\n          cb-validation="verifyRequest" autocomplete="off">\n        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">\n            <label class="control-label">{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.findCompany\' | translate}}</label>\n            <div class="listCompany">\n                <div class="typeahead">\n                    <input type="text" name="company" cb-validate\n                        class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="companySelected"\n                        aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false"\n                        typeahead="company.description for company in retrieveCompanies($viewValue)"\n                        typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"\n                        typeahead-min-length="3"\n                        typeahead-wait-ms="300"/>\n                    <div cb-validate-errors="company"></div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n\n        </div>\n\n        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">\n            <label> {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.nickname\' | translate}}<sup tooltip-html-unsafe="{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.nicknameMessage\' | translate}}"><i class="icon-info"></i></sup></label>\n            <input type="text" name="nickname" class="form-control" ng-model="verifyRequest.nickname" maxlength="35"/>\n        </div>\n        \n        <div class="col-xs-12 " ng-show="showCompanyCodeError()"><p class="text-danger">\n            {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.companyCodeErrorMessage\'|translate}}</p></div>\n        <div class="col-xs-12 " ng-show="showNoCompanyError()"><p class="text-danger">\n            {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.companyError\'|translate}}</p></div>\n\n        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">\n            <label> {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.uniqueReference\' | translate}}<sup\n                    tooltip-html-unsafe="è il codice identificativo della tua utenza,</br> ti viene fornito dall\'azienda creditrice"><i\n                    class="icon-info"></i></sup>\n            </label>\n            <div>\n                <input type="text" name="refMandate" class="form-control" ng-model="verifyRequest.refMandate"\n                       maxlength="35" cb-validate/>\n                <div cb-validate-errors="refMandate"></div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="col-xs-6">\n            <label> {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.heading\' | translate}} </label>\n            <div class="typeahead">\n                <select cb-select name="holder" ng-model="verifyRequest.holder" cb-datasource="holders"\n                        cb-validate cb-return-value="true" ng-required="submitted"></select>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="col-xs-12">\n            <div class="row">\n                <div class="col-xs-12">\n                    <label> {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.operationType\' | translate}} </label>\n                </div>\n                <div class="col-xs-3">\n                    <label class="radio-inline">\n                        <input type="radio" cb-radio name="operation" ng-value="true"\n                               ng-model="verifyRequest.isRecurring"\n                               label="{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.recurrent\' | translate}}"/>\n                    </label>\n                </div>\n                <div class="col-xs-3">\n                    <label class="radio-inline">\n                        <input type="radio" cb-radio name="operation" ng-value="false"\n                               ng-model="verifyRequest.isRecurring"\n                               label="{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.single\' | translate}}"/>\n                    </label>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n\n        <div ui-view="add-customize" autoscroll="false" class="col-xs-12"></div>\n\n        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center padding-top padding-bottom">\n            <button cb-button class="btn-active btn-lg" cb-ui-sref="directDebit.retrieve">\n                {{\'cbLabels.directDebit.deleteUser\' | translate}}\n            </button>\n            <button cb-button class="btn-brand btn-lg" cb-validate-form="" cb-ui-sref="directDebit.create.verify"\n                    cb-param-name="createVerifyRequest"\n                    ng-model="verifyRequest">{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.addUser\' | translate}}\n            </button>\n        </div>\n    </form>\n</div>\n\n'
    }), define("accounts/widgets/domiciliazione-utenze/states/create/prepare/_controllers/DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController", [], function() {
        "use strict";

        function DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController($scope, prepareResponse, $stateParams, cbUpstreamStates, cbHalInterface) {
            function convertCompanies(companies) {
                return _.forEach(companies, function(company) {
                    company.description = company.value + " - " + company.key
                }), companies
            }
            var retrievedCompanies = [],
                retrievedCompaniesDone = !1;
            $scope.verifyRequest = {}, $scope.avatars = _.range(54), $scope.verifyRequest.isRecurring = !0, $scope.holders = prepareResponse.holders, $scope.verifyRequest.holder = $scope.holders[0].value, cbUpstreamStates.set($scope.holders, "holders", 2), $scope.selectAvatar = function(avatar) {
                    $scope.verifyRequest.avatar = avatar
                }, $scope.retrieveCompanies = function(filter) {
                    return retrievedCompaniesDone = !1, cbHalInterface.getRelatedResource("self", {
                        company: filter.trim()
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        return retrievedCompaniesDone = !0, retrievedCompanies = convertCompanies(response.companies)
                    })
                }, $scope.$watch("companySelected", function(companyDescription) {
                    var company = _.find(retrievedCompanies, {
                        description: companyDescription
                    });
                    company && ($scope.verifyRequest.company = {
                        key: company.key,
                        value: company.value
                    })
                }),
                function(createPrepareRequest) {
                    return createPrepareRequest && Object.keys(createPrepareRequest).length > 0
                }($stateParams.editParams) && ($scope.verifyRequest = $stateParams.editParams, $scope.companySelected = $stateParams.editParams.company.value + " - " + $stateParams.editParams.company.key), $scope.showCompanyCodeError = function() {
                    return $scope.verifyRequest && $scope.verifyRequest.company && _.isEmpty($scope.verifyRequest.company.key)
                }, $scope.showNoCompanyError = function() {
                    return $scope.companySelected && $scope.companySelected.length > 2 && retrievedCompaniesDone && _.isEmpty(retrievedCompanies)
                }
        }
        return DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController.$inject = ["$scope", "prepareResponse", "$stateParams", "cbUpstreamStates", "cbHalInterface"], DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController
    }), define("text!accounts/widgets/domiciliazione-utenze/states/create/prepare/_views/add-customize.html", [], function() {
        return '<label class="control-label">{{\'cbLabels.directDebit.selectAvatar\' | translate}}</label>\n<div cb-carousel=""\n     cb-refresh-on="[addressBook.avatars, panels.customize.visible]">\n    <ul class="circle-list margin-bottom margin-top">\n        <li ng-repeat="avatar in avatars"\n            ng-class="{active: verifyRequest.avatar == avatar}">\n            <a ng-click="selectAvatar(avatar)">\n                <div cb-avatar-icon="avatar" class="img"></div>\n            </a>\n        </li>\n    </ul>\n</div>\n'
    }), define("accounts/widgets/domiciliazione-utenze/states/create/prepare/config", ["text!./_views/addressbook-new.html", "./_controllers/DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController", "text!./_views/add-customize.html"], function(AddressbookNewTmpl, DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController, AddCustomizeTmpl) {
        "use strict";

        function CreatePrepareConfig($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state("directDebit.create.prepare", {
                params: {
                    createPrepareRequest: {},
                    editParams: {}
                },
                parent: "directDebit.retrieve",
                resolve: {
                    prepareResponse: ["cbStateResolve", "$stateParams", function(cbStateResolve, $stateParams) {
                        return cbStateResolve("directDebit.create.prepare", "start", $stateParams)
                    }]
                },
                views: {
                    "addressbook-new@directDebit.retrieve": {
                        controller: DomiciliazioneUtenzeCreatePrepareController,
                        template: AddressbookNewTmpl
                    },
                    "add-customize@directDebit.create.prepare": {
                        template: AddCustomizeTmpl
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        return CreatePrepareConfig.$inject = ["$stateProvider"], CreatePrepareConfig
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it's exactly FF executing that function. Seems like it's some other framework that will read this and produce some runnable JS code for it.

Comment: @VLAZ how do I debug this and find the relevant .JSON file?

Comment: 1. It's not going to be a JSON file, as that only carries data. It;s a JS file. 2. Depends on what is actually handling that. Some frameworks have a debug plugin for the browser that allows you to examine the context of a binding directly. Others allow you to do something similar in some capacity using other debug tools. It's going to be specific for whatever is reading and using that. If no tool is available (or known), then you can probably search for `retrieveCompanies` in your project and try and find the declaration then work from there.

Comment: @VLAZ i dont have a local project, I'm looking at a live webiste, I need to input a company name but they are using weird names instea legal names, so if I can lookup the course Ill just search by ID thing that is not possible from the web interface. The only reference I could find is this one: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Apr/08/Using-the-ngBootStrap-TypeAhead-Control-with-Dynamic-Data but it is not clear to me where it is supposed to be the source database.

Comment: Oh...in that case your task is in some ways harder but also in some ways easier. You can open the dev tools (F12) then go to the Debugger tab and search in all files using Ctrl+Shift+F. That's is searching through all JS code that is executed. It's easier, since you don't have extra project files that are removed on build. It's harder because after building it might not be as easy to look at the code and understand it if it was minified.

Comment: @VLAZ with your indication I was able to retrieve the source code finally, I have added it to the original post, used a JS beautifier to format it since as you supposed it was minified.